# how to classify the whole data set in weka

Tags: weka, supervised-learning

I've got a supervised data set with 6836 instances, and I need to know the predictions of my model for all the instances, not only for a test set.

I followed the approach train-test (2/3-1/3) to know about my rates TPR and FPR, and I've got the predictions about my test (1/3), but I need to know the predcitions about all the 6836 instances.

How can I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the classify tab in Weka Explorer there should be a button that says 'More options...' if you go in there you should be able to output predictions as plain text. If you use cross validation rather than a percentage split you will get predictions for all instances in a table like this:

```
+-------+--------+-----------+-------+------------+
| inst# | actual | predicted | error | prediction |
+-------+--------+-----------+-------+------------+
| 1     | 2:no   | 1:yes     | +     | 0.926      |
| 2     | 1:yes  | 1:yes     |       | 0.825      |
| 1     | 2:no   | 1:yes     | +     | 0.636      |
| 2     | 1:yes  | 1:yes     |       | 0.808      |
| ...   | ...    | ...       | ...   | ...        |
+-------+--------+-----------+-------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do cross validation you also can create a data set containing all your data (training + test) and add it as test data. Then you can go to more options and show the results as Campino already answered.